# ASP.Net Image Button Delete confirmation using jQuery UI Dialog

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, webforms

I am using a repeater to display rows of data. Each row has a delete Image button. I would like to add a confirmation dialog using jQuery UI. The Dialog box displays correctly when the delete Image Button is clicked. What I am unsure about is how do I call the event handler for the Image button from jQuery when the OK button is clicked on the Dialog box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do some thing like this, check for [Jquery Dialogbox](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation) example,
while binding the Repeater you attach the event handler to it. like this

```
yourbutton.Attributes.Add("onclick","Deletbox('" + yourDeleteID + "'))";
```

javascript function :

```
var deleteId;//this the global variable to hold the value 


function Deletebox(ID)
{
  ( "#YourDialog" ).data('DeleteID',ID).dialog('open');
}
```

this is for the dialogbox initializer

```
     $( "#YourDialog" ).dialog({
                    modal: true, //this will make a modal form
                                open:function()
                                {
                                      deleteId=$(this).data('DeleteID'); 
                                },
                    buttons: { // this is the buttons which you are going to show in box
                        "Delete all items": function() {
                            CallYourdeletionMethodFromServer(deleteId)// by using $.Ajax function
                        },
                        Cancel: function() {
                            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: I have a repeater_ItemCommand event handler wired up which gets the ID for deletion from the CommandArgument and then calls the method to delete the record. How do I call this event handler directly from jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the `__doPostBack` function in your OK button click handler.  You'll need to preserve what the ID was of the button that was originally clicked to open your dialog and pass that as the first argument.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="Parent">
        <div>
            test1
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="Deletemessage(1,this);" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="Parent">
        <div>
            test2
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="Deletemessage(1,this);" />
        </div>
    </div>


function Deletemessage(id, obj) {
            $('<div></div>').appendTo('body')
                    .html('<div><h6>Are you want to delete this part?</h6></div>')
                    .dialog({
                        modal: true, title: 'Delete message', zIndex: 10000, autoOpen: true,
                        width: 'auto', modal: true, resizable: false,
                        buttons: {
                            Ok: function () {
                                $(obj).removeAttr('onclick');

                                //                                $.ajax({
                                //                                    url: '/yourPath', type: 'Post', dataType: 'json',
                                //                                    data: { 'id': id },
                                //                                    success: function (data) {
                                $(obj).parents('.Parent').remove();

                                //Or

                                //window.location.reload();

                                //                                    }
                                //                                });

                                $(this).dialog("close");
                            },
                            Cancel: function () {
                                $(this).dialog("close");
                            }
                        },
                        close: function (event, ui) {
                            $(this).remove();
                        }
                    });
        };
```

for live demo see this link: http://jsfiddle.net/nanoquantumtech/9NKXq/

Comment: function Deletemessage(id, name, obj) -> Deletemessage(1, 'test name', this);